# Operating system windows xp on optiplex 790

Tags: windows

I had to convert my Dell Optiplex 790 from Windows 7 to XP because I am using an application that will not run on the newer OS.
The following drivers are not installed:

- Ethernet controller
- pci device
- pci simple communication controller
- sm bus controller
- video controller (vga compatible)

My laptop does not support this hardware on XP.

Comment: If Dell does not provide Windows XP drivers for those devices you will have to hope that native drivers are supplied by Microsoft through Windows Update.  If no drivers are available the you will have to live without those devices.  Your question is also very hard to read and the reason for my downvote.

Comment: For once I agree with Ramhound, why are you trying to install a 12 year old OS to a Dell 790?

Comment: Even if Dell doesn't provide the drivers, if you can identify the hardware OEM, you may be able to find drivers on the manufacturer's site - unlikely, but worth checking.  i.e. your network card is likely a Realtek something or other, so you could check if Realtek has drivers.  Motherboard drivers you may be out of luck since Dell uses custom boards . . .

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Browse_For_Drivers/Desktops/Optiplex/OptiPlex%20790/Network/Driver/) a link to the network drivers for the Dell Optiplex 790, put the network driver on a USB and install in on your fresh XP install. Once you have an internet connection, then use windows updates to get the rest of the drivers.

However I don't recommend running XP on a standalone desktop, [the OS is being phased out](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/endofsupport.aspx). Instead, if you need it for a certain program, run an install inside a Virtual Machine on a Windows 7 or 8 host.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a license for Windows 7 Pro or Enterprise, I would reinstall it and download the free Windows XP Mode which allows you to run a virtualized copy of XP under the Win7.  Many of the newer motherboards don't have XP drivers to allow you to run natively.